# Gradle Version Catalog specify library build type

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, toml

I'm refactoring a multi module project with version catalogs and I have to add a dependency that is currently like this:

```
implementation com.mygroup:my-artifact:1.0.0:debug@aar
```

Since version catalogs doesn't allow to specify the `aar` type, a workaround would be to specify it directly in the gradle file like this:

```
implementation(libs.myDependency) { artifact { type = 'aar' } }
```

This works, but there's an extra complexity: I need to also specify the build type, in the example from above is `debug`, I cannot find a way to add it.

What I've tried is:

**TOML**

```
[libraries]
myDependency = { module = "com.mygroup:my-artifact", version = "1.0.0:debug" }
```

**Gradle**

```
implementation(libs.myDependency) { artifact { type = 'aar' } }
```

For some reason this doesn't work, how can I also specify the build type?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found a way to do this! Need to add the `classifier` into the `artifact`.

So for the given regular declaration:

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation com.mygroup:my-artifact:1.0.0:debug@aar
}
```

The version catalogs way would be:

**TOML**

```ini
[libraries]
myDependency = { module = "com.mygroup:my-artifact", version = "1.0.0" }
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.myDependency) {
        artifact {
            classifier = 'debug'
            type = 'aar'
        }
    }

}
```